# Unity WebGL jslib Plugins all give undefined symbol when imported

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm trying to follow a basic tutorial for getting jslib plugins working in Unity. Even the basic "Hello, world!" example  given in the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) gives me an "undefined symbol" error in Unity 2021.3. I've poked around looking for solutions to this, but most that I've seen were tied to misspelling function names or not being in the Plugins folder, both of which I've verified are correct in my code.

The .jslib file is:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library,
{
    Hello: function()
    {
        window.alert("Hello, world!");
    }
});
```

The .cs file is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class importtest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void Hello();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Library\Bee\artifacts\WebGL\build\debug_WebGL_wasm\build.js: undefined symbol: Hello (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ProcessEvent(int,intptr,bool&)
```

So far, I've verified everything is copy/pasted directly from the documentation, the filepaths are correct, and there are no other errors/code in the Unity project.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when updating Unity version.
You need to close the project, delete **"Library"** folder from project's root directory and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when upgrading my project from `2022 LTS` to `2023`. I also tried validating misspelled names and deleting "Library" folder. None of them helped.

**The Fix:**
I got it working again by deleting all my `.jslib` files and their imports/calls from scripts. Then created a new `.jslib`  with a different name. Then add some dummy functions like "PrintHelloWorld" and test it. Hopefully your "PrintHelloWorld" will work. Then start adding you functions back into this new file and they will work again like a charm.

PS: Seems like while upgrading your project to `Unity 2023` messes up import configurations of `jslib` files that's why older files doesnt work but newly added files work. Although I'm not sure about it.